# Bugzilla - Table already exists: bz_schema at Bugzilla/DB/Schema.pm

Tags: postgresql, centos, bugzilla

I'm having some trouble installing bugzilla on a postgreSQL DB. on a centOS server.
When running the checksetup.pl file the output end with :

```
Reading ./localconfig...
Checking for               DBD-Pg (v2.7.0)    ok: found v2.19.3
Checking for           PostgreSQL (v8.03.0000) ok: found v09.05.0400
Checking for               DBD-Pg (v2.19.3)   ok: found v2.19.3

Creating database bugs_pg...
Adding new table bz_schema...
Initializing bz_schema...
Table already exists: bz_schema at Bugzilla/DB/Schema.pm line 2702.
```

On a newly create database.
I saw this page saying it was a bug with postgreSQL but my version is already update.
http://mozilla.6506.n7.nabble.com/Bugzilla-Perl-and-Postgress-installation-problem-td62236.html

My user has the right to create it without problems (I asume...)

```
 Nom du rôle(role name) |                                    Attributs                                    | Membre de
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 bugsPG      | Créer une base (Create database)                                                                  | {}
 postgres    | Superutilisateur, Créer un rôle, Créer une base, Réplication, Contournement RLS | {}
```

EDIT: I even tried  to import a working bugzilla DB:
Export:

```
pg_dump --no-privileges --no-owner -h localhost -U bugs -d bugs > bugs_pg.sql
```

Create DB:

```
CREATE DATABASE bugs OWNER bugs;
```

Finally :

```
psql -p 5434 -f bugs_pg.sql
```

And still the mighty bz_schema...

```
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
CREATE EXTENSION
COMMENT
SET
SET
SET
psql:bugs_pg.sql:44: ERREUR:  la relation « bz_schema » existe déjà (Bz_schema exist already)
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally resintall Bugzilla from 0 and the pgsql base as well, it's seem to work fine now.